# Convert a Gson Array within an Object

Tags: java, gson, retrofit, android

I am trying to extract "levels" from this server response. I am a bit new to Android Development. I need help parsing this API response to a List of a POJO.

```
    {
  "levels": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "level": 0,
      "name": "Level 0"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "level": 1,
      "name": "Level 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

A kotlin Data Class for the Level:

```
data class Level(var id:Int, var level: Int, var name: String?=null)
```

Here is a custom Gson Deserializer
JsonDeserializer:

```
public class RestDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {
    private Class<T> clasz;
    private String key;

    public RestDeserializer(Class<T> clasz, String key) {
        this.clasz = clasz;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(
            JsonElement jsonElement,
            Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext
    ) throws JsonParseException{
        JsonElement content = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get(key);
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, clasz);
    }
}
```

Retrofit Client:

```
interface LevelService {
    @GET("api/levels")
    fun getLevels():Call<List<Level>>

    companion object {
        fun levels(context: Context): LevelService{
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Level.class, new RestDeserializer<>(Level[].class, "levels"))
                .create();
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
            return retrofit.create(LevelService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally Call:

```
fun getLevels(){
        val apiService = LevelService.levels(applicationContext)
        apiService.getLevels().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Level>>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Level>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("Error: FATAL)", "Error:(")
                t!!.printStackTrace()
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Level>>?, response: Response<List<Level>>?) {
                if (response!!.isSuccessful){

                    Log.d("SUCCESS", response.body().toString())
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("Error:)", response.errorBody().toString())
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

But it is failing giving an errorI hope its clear:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

StakeTrace is as follows:

```
 W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:122)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:217)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:116)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace of the logcat?  The error you posted doesn't give enough information, like what line of the code it errors out.  Also point out what line the stacktrace says the error is at.

Comment: I just added the trace,hope its informative

Answer (score 0):

You have to change **RestDeserializer** to get the values from JsonArray rather than directly from JsonObject.

```
JsonArray array = je.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray(key);
```

Comment: Not sure where I might be missing it, I've just changed but the error is still there!!

Comment: You need to iterate JsonArray and convert to Gson object